# Кастомный ListView не реагирует на события

Tags: android

Есть кастомный ListView. Вот разметка

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtAlphabet"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_button"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txtWord"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="left|center" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_star_outline_black"
        android:id="@+id/btnFavorites"
        android:background="@drawable/white_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

В этот список выводится слова из БД. Как сделать так чтобы при клике на пункт списка что-то выполнялось. А если нажать на кнопку в пункте из списка что-то другое выполнялось. У меня до этого был такой код для обычного ListView, но он не работает после того как я кастомизировал список

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //что-то
    }
});
```

Вот такой эксепшн выкидывает

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.proj1, PID: 7062
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
at test.proj1.MainActivity$3.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:231)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1155)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3120)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4047)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3806)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9943)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2663)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10163)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4052)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6210)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6184)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6145)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6313)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

На строку `CharSequence strCharSequence = ((TextView) view).getText();` ругается из метода

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Word.class);
        CharSequence strCharSequence = ((TextView) view).getText();
        String str = strCharSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();;
        String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка закономерная: `view` -- это корневой элемент, он `LinearLayout`, что видно из описания разметки. Чтобы получить доступ к `TextView` внутри него, нужно использовать `findViewById()`:

```
(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtWord)
```

Comment: понял, а как реализовать клик по нажатию на кнопку btnFavorites? отдельный метод нужно сделать?

Comment: как всегда - повесить на него лиснер. но, поскольку это ListView, то лиснер придется вешать в адаптере в onCreateView и дальше решать задачу, как этот лиснер будет получать информацию, к какому элементу он привязан. я бы этот лиснер создавал в holder, но это уже другая история.

Comment: А можно ссылку на какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: вот, например: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview

Comment: А прямо в MainActivity нельзя как-то реализовать это? Просто у меня по нажатию на кнопку из ListView должно в БД записываться что-то

Comment: зачем для записи в БД тебе activity?

Comment: У меня из БД выводятся в этот кастомный listview слова. Я хочу чтобы по нажатию на эту кнопку из listview в колонку из таблицы БД записывалось значение типа пометка что это избранное слово. Собственно  у меня это сделано в другом активити тоже, но хотелось бы и на главном такое реализовать